# Get a specific column value from multi array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How to fetch a multi array branch?
For example, I have following array:

```
$newarr= Array ( 
  "Tommy" => Array ( Array ( "a" => 25, "b" => 304, "c" => 9277 ), 
     Array ( "a" => 25, "b" => 4, "c" => 23 ) 
  ) ,
  "Garry" => Array ( Array ( "a" => 23, "b" => 285, "c" => 8678 ) ,
     Array ( "a" => 23, "b" => 9, "c" => 4 ) 
  )
) ;
```

How to use foreach to call [Tommy][1] and [Garry][1] only?

I tried the below code.

```
foreach ($person as $name => $choice?[1]?)
  { 
    foreach ($choice?[1]? as $value)
        { 
           echo "<div class='col-md-6'><br>"; 
           echo $name. "<br>"; 
           echo $value?[1]?["a"]."tries <br>";
           echo $value?[1]?["b"]."times <br>"; 
           echo $value?[1]?["c"]."count <br></div>";
        }
  }
```

I need output as follows:

```
Tommy
25
304
9277

Garry
23
285
8678
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide the code that you tried

Comment: foreach ($person as $name => $choice?[1]?) {
  foreach ($choice?[1]? as $value) {
 echo "<div class='col-md-6'><br>";
 echo $name. "<br>";
 echo $value?[1]?["a"]."tries <br>";
  echo $value?[1]?["b"]."times <br>";
   echo $value?[1]?["c"]."count <br></div>";}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `foreach` like as

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value){
   $result[$key] = $value[1];
}
```

**Edited**

```
$result = [];
foreach($newarr as $key => $value){
   echo "$key<br>";
     foreach($value[1] as $v){
        echo "$v<br>";
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand on this? What are next steps?

Comment: Check [this](https://eval.in/451958). I think then you can simply use as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `foreach` loop for this.

```
$required = array();
foreach ($arr as $elem) {
  $required[] = $elem[1];
}
```

**Explanation:**

You can use foreach to loop over an array.

You can use either key value pair or just values if needed.

In your case, you need elements from second level sub array.

so, use foreach to get key `1`

Comment: Could you please review my question, I understood that I can use foreach, not sure how to specify location.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map)

```
$result = array_map(function($item) {
  return $item[1];
}, $inputArray);
```

Comment: Ok, which function do I need?